# Is there a way to prove that $\sqrt[7]{129}$ is irrational using the following theorem?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

I want to prove that $\sqrt[7]{129}$ is **irrational** using the following theorem:

Let $n,k$ be **natural numbers**. Then, $\sqrt[n]{k}$ is rational **iff** $k$ is the $n\text{-th}$ power of a (natural) **number**.

**Attempt:**
Let $\sqrt[7]{129}\in\mathbb{Q}.$ So, there are positive integers $m,n$ with $GCF(m,n)=1$ such that $\sqrt[7]{129}=\frac{m}{n}.$ If $n>1,$ there is a **prime** $p$ such that $p\mid n,$ thus, $129n^7=m^7.$ So, $p\mid m^7=m\cdot m\cdots m\Leftrightarrow p\mid m.$ 
That doesn't holds because $GCF(m,n)=1.$ So $n=1$ and $129=m^7.$ Now, $m$ **has to be** an **odd** number, let it be $m=2k+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}.$ $\text{Or,}$ $$129=(2k+1)^7.$$
(I really have No idea what step follows next. Any help would be appreciated.)

Comment: You're overcomplicating it: how big is $2^7$?  How big is $3^7$? what do you know about the function $x\mapsto x^7$ on the natural numbers?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Is it a proof to say $2^7<129$, $3^7>129$ ?

Comment: You also need the fact that $n\mapsto n^7$ is an increasing function, but yes, that's perfectly legitimate.  Any integer $n$ satisfying $n^7=129$ would have to satisfy $2\lt n\lt 3$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  Well, thank you very much

Comment: Is the theorem even correct? $\sqrt[3]{1/8}$ is also a rational number, even though the base is not a natural number ($0.5^3=1/8$). Or do you have to read "(natural) number" as "rational number"?

Comment: @Coodey Your example fails the criterion that the radicand (in your case, $\frac 18$) is a natural number.

Comment: @Coodey Do you know what "natural number" means ?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you! Seems like I misinterpreted "iff" in the theorem. Since $n$ and $k$ are already defined to be natural numbers (in the first sentence), my example is not excluded to be a rational number. There is simply no explicit statement about this.

Answer (score 3):

$2^7=128$, $3^7>3^5=243>129$. Hence $m$ cannot be an integer.

Comment: $(2.002)^7\approx 129.$ Isn't $2.002\in\mathbb{Q}$  ?

Comment: You have chosen $m$ to be integer right?

Comment: Sure. Regardless of my attempt, can this answer be a proof for that ?

Comment: @user180321 the answer by SiongthyeGoh is correct.  While $(2.002)^7\approx 129$, that doesn't help us at all.  We want to know for which $m$ that $m^7=129$.  You have a theorem above that says that $\sqrt[n]{k}$ is rational if $k$ is the $n$th power of some natural number.  This is a statement $P\implies Q$.  We can then use the _contrapositive_ of this statement, which says that $\neg Q\implies \neg P$.  If the contrapositive is true, the original statement is true.

So, now our theorem says if $k$ isn't the $n$th power of a natural number, then $\sqrt[n]{k}$ isn't rational.

Comment: @Mark thanks! $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $